# VC2005 got slower after installing VC2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, manifest

I have installed VS2008 SP1 and now when I compiled solution (a mix of C++ and managed C++ projects) it takes much more time to embed the manifest into .dll.

Is it a known issue? Any workarounds/directions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a known issue.  Time to defrag your hard drive.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that old 20 GB hard drive had finally met its match.